# there's a problem while doing cross compilation using crosstool-ng

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile gcc for taget=powerpc7448 and the  host system is linux,I downloaded crosstool-ng and extracted also after this I am configuring with the command ./configure --prefix=,but I am getting the error bash path,I am going to attach the screenshot please go through that one ,and let me know what I am doing wrong,how do I solve that error.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czXeF.png)

Comment: Your "Debian" OS must have the usual requirements for compiling gcc, etc., e.g. `/bin/sh` must be a link to `/bin/bash`. ... Note : Please do not show pictures of text https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7lye0fcoi1nf0z/Images-about.txt?dl=0

Comment: thankyou for the replay,could you please tell me more about the requirements for compiling gcc,I searched and I got ,I need to install build-essential packages,so already I installed that one  and I am trying to to link /bin/sh to /bin/bash via giving the command "ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh" after this I am trying to configure but getting the same error..

Comment: The general gcc build requirements : `# apt install g++ flex bison gettext dejagnu sharutils texinfo doxygen binutils-dev elfutils libelf-dev`. .... Your error : Could be a "crosstool-ng issue" ?